# makemigrations - No changes detected -Django

Tags: django

I am new to `Django`, and im trying to create a company profile for user to fill up.
when i make migrations, i got the following error which is no changes detect.

heres the `model.py`

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    about = models.TextField(gettext_lazy('about'), max_length=500, blank=True)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    contact=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

I didnt create anything in other .py file only `model` and i have another class which is profile in the same `model.py` as company.

Do correct or lmk if i make any mistake, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your app must be included in `INSTALLED_APPS` first (inside `settings.py`).

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    '<myapp>',
    ...
]
```

After that you can run

```sh
python manage.py makemigrations <myapp>
```

Comment: i tried this :( and it showed 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '<my app>''

Comment: You should replace `<my app>` with your application name. The same one you used in your `python manage.py startapp` command

Comment: okay I made some changes and it says "No changes detected in app <myapp>"

Comment: I have exact same issue and there is no way to fix this.